# Hydra THC - Get failed login

Tags: hydra

I'm trying to get a password from a website (From my account, I know the password) using Hydra. The problem: I can't find any usable feedback from the website telling Hydra if the password is wrong or not, so every password gets accepted.

I'm currently using:

```
hydra -l SchR-esgf -p NotMyPass [IP] http-post-form "/users/login/index.php:data[User][username]=^USER^&data[User][username]=^PASS^:Login failed" -V -f -s 443
```

I thought about getting the `<div>-authMessage` for checking, but I couldn't find out how (and I've been googling for two hours now).

Comment: Do you know how to tell hydra about auth success by scraping content off of the page that shows up after successful login?

Comment: No I don't. I just know a little bit about hydra. Could you tell me how to do it? I could provide you the Wireshark output if it helps.

Comment: the manual tells you how to do this: `S=`